# How can I make a Plot over a discrete set of domain points?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the function $y=2^x$ at the $x$-values given by `Table[Prime[n], {n,20}]`

How should I write the plot function? Like so?

```
list = Table[Prime[n], {n,20}]
Plot[y = 2^x, Evaluate[list]]
```

Comment: [ListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html). To connect the dots: `Joined->True` or [ListLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html).

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I'd like to pass the result of a Table[] as the Plot[] range "{x,min, max}"

Comment: How can ListPlot be used to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to look at the syntax structure for `Plot`. You simply need a function, and then the variable range in the form `{x,xmin,xmax}`.

Comment: Ok. Then let me reword the question. How can I tell Mathematica to plot y=2^x for x =Table[Prime[n],{n,20}]

Comment: Do you mean `ListPlot[2^list]`, or better still `ListLogPlot[2^list]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the solutions so far have plotted `{n, 2^Prime[n]}` for integer values of `n`, which means that the points will be evenly spaced along the horizontal axis.  Here's how to do what was actually asked, plotting `{x, 2^x}` for prime values of `x`.

*Since `2^x` grows so quickly, I'll demonstrate instead with `Sqrt[x]` so that it's easier to see the uneven distribution of primes along the horizontal axis.*

- Using `ListPlot`, you want to specify the horizontal position using `{x,y}` pairs, rather than just a list of heights:

  ```
  primes = Table[Prime[n], {n, 20}];
  ListPlot[Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, primes}]]
  ```

  [image]
- Using `DiscretePlot`, you want to provide the horizontal positions using the `{x, {x1, x2, ..., xn}}` variable specification:

  ```
  primes = Table[Prime[n], {n, 20}];
  DiscretePlot[Sqrt[x], {x, primes}]
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use a function dedicated to plotting discrete data:

```
DiscretePlot[2^Prime[n], {n, 1, 7}, Filling -> None, Frame -> True, Joined -> True]
```

[image: exponential at prime values]

Answer (score 3):

```
x = Table[Prime[n], {n, 20}];
y = 2^x;
ListLinePlot[y]
```

Comment: OMG!! you're the god and I really need to learn the mathematica basics here!! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: No problem. You can start from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

**Exponential** functions increase too fast:

```
ListPlot[2^Table[Prime[n], {n, 20}], Joined -> True]
```

[image: exponential at prime values]

Instead, it is better to work with `ListLogPlot` (plotting a given function in the logarithmic scale) or just `DiscretePlot` of the `Log` :

```
GraphicsRow[
    { ListLogPlot[2^Table[Prime[n], {n, 20}], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
      DiscretePlot[Log[2^Prime[n]], {n, 20},  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]}]
```

[image: plots of logarithms]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.